# Ubuntu 22.04 vs 20.04, different X11 forwarding behavior, WHY?

Tags: desktop-environments, x11-forwarding

Please see my screenshot below:

[image: OpenSUSE SSH into Ubuntu 22.04, running 2 different X Window GUI apps]

My actions:

- I have two Linux machines:

  - Ub22cppdev: Ubuntu 22.04, as SSH server, IP=10.22.4.55 .
  - osuse15b: openSUSE 15.5, as SSH client, IP=10.22.4.61 .
- On osuse15b, start a Konsole terminal window, type in `ssh -X 10.22.4.55`, so it SSH logins to the Ubuntu server. The `-X` parameter, we know, enables X11 forwarding, so I hope that GUI programs run from Ubuntu server can display the GUI back on my SSH client's screen.
- In osuse15b's Konsole window, after SSH login success, run `dclock &`, I see dclock window appears on osuse15b's X Window desktop. This is the desired behavior.
- Then in osuse15b's Konsole window, I type `gnome-mines`. Now the weird behavior. **The mine sweeper GUI appears on Ubuntu's own X Window desktop.** That's definitely not what I expect.

Besides gnome-mines, Ubuntu stock GUI programs like `gedit`, `gnome-characters`, behave the same way.

Why does Ubuntu 22.04 exhibit such weird behavior, or any settings/workaround to fix it?

I've tried Ubuntu 20.04 as well, the 20.04 works as desired, i.e., `gnome-mines` displays it window on SSH client-side machine.

Comment: In your ssh session, type `echo $DISPLAY`
If X forwarding is active, you should get something like `localhost:10.0` indicating that any GUI applications should connect to local display 10.0, which is the X tunnel back to the client machine. If you don't get that, then it's puzzling why dclock displays where you want it. Otherwise, it's puzzling why the other programs do not. Let's first distinguish between the two cases.

Comment: Yes, at the position I typed `dclock -seconds` (timestamp `2024-03-19 15:19:38`) in my screenshot, had I typed `echo $DISPLAY` there, it did show `localhost:10.0`.

Comment: It works fine on my system. gnome-mines and gedit both respect the DISPLAY environment variable. So I have no further suggestions except maybe to double-check that DISPLAY is set correctly when you try the other programs.

Comment: Thank you for trying that. But, I've installed a fresh new Ubuntu instance from official **ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso** and only have `sudo apt install openssh-server` applied, and it behaves so. Maybe I should turn to other friends to verify this.